# Existe alguna herramienta para buscar Preguntas/Respuesta realizadas por un usuario que fue eliminado?

Tags: soporte

Hace algun tiempo atras, indague sobre el tema, *Existe alguna herramienta para buscar Preguntas/respuesta realizadas por un usuario que fue eliminado?*

encontre una solucion y la he perdido, por eso ahora me gustaria que queda documentada aqui en el sitio y verificar quien mas apoya la iniciativa:

estoy intentandio buscar las preguntas y respuesta del usuario eliminado ***user46896***:

este es un ejemplo de una respuesta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385608/315134

Comment: No, yo se que aqui hay una herramienta propia de SE para esto... y es sobre los query la idea es documentar aqui en Meta como se implementa, solo que perdi el link

Comment: Si te sirve de algo, [acá](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/revision/1762118/2141519/encontrar-todos-los-posts-de-un-usuario-eliminado) te dejo el `query` para buscar en es.stackoverflow.com. Hacerlo es bastante sencillo.

Comment: si pero no trae respuestas XD, voy a jugar con el ahora en la noche

Comment: Diría que se te olvido hacer algo, porque [si trae respuestas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrzVP.png)

Comment: @Marcos pero quitaste el link

Comment: [Este link?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866217/select-all-posts-from-deleted-user?DeletedUserUsername=user46896). Igual, si entras al que esta en el segundo comentario (_[este](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/revision/1762118/2141519/encontrar-todos-los-posts-de-un-usuario-eliminado)_), es una copia del primero.